# Azure Cloud services project - disable autostart on debug

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, projects-and-solutions

I don't know if this is a common behavior, or something in my configuration is missing, but my Azure Solution in Visual studio 2012 starts two browser instances every time i hit F5. I think it has to do with how many endpoints i have defined in the "CloudConfiguration" settings.

PS: In a normal web application project this behavior is defined in Project->Propertes->Web->Start Acton->Dont open a page.... . This seems not to work debuging Azure project.

How to disable the auto start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - two tabs open because you have two endpoints defined.  Right-click on the web role and select properties, then under Configuration >> Startup Action - select/deselect the endpoints you want to launch:

[image: Endpoints]

Comment: cool. thanks! 
Somehow having 2 places for 1 and the same property.